# What is the probability at least one of the balls has the number "1" on it?

Tags: probability

We have three boxes, the first one contains 5 numbered balls, the second box contains 8 numbered balls and the third box contains 9 numbered balls.

We choose randomly one ball of each box.

What is the probability at least one of the balls has the number "1" on it?

I have done the following:

Let X be the number of balls with "1" on it.

Then $P(X\geq 1)=1-P(X<1)=1-P(X=0)$.

In the first box there are $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to get a ball with "1" on it, in the second box there are $\binom{7}{1}$ ways to get a ball with "1" on it and in the third box there are $\binom{8}{1}$ ways to get a ball with "1" on it, right?

Then the number of ways to get one ball out of each box is $\binom{5}{1}+\binom{8}{1}+\binom{9}{1}$, or not?

Does it holds then that $$P(X=0)=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\cdot \binom{4}{1}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot \binom{7}{1}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot \binom{8}{1}}{\binom{5}{1}+\binom{8}{1}+\binom{9}{1}}\quad ?$$

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing here. 5 balls, so where does $\frac{1}{3}{4\choose1}$ come from? But you are almost certainly double counting. You need to calculate the probability of getting no 1s, which is $\frac{4}{5}\frac{7}{8}\frac{8}{9}$, then one minus that is the prob of getting at least one.

Comment: Ahh... So is the result $P(X\geq 1)=1-\frac{4}{5}\cdot \frac{7}{8}\cdot \frac{8}{9}$ ? @almagest

Comment: Presumably there is exactly one “number $1$” ball in each box? Otherwise you could put balls $6$ through $14$ in the second box. Or write the number $1$ on every ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $\frac{17}{45}$.

You can compute the probability of *not* getting a ball with a $1$ on it and take the complement. For each box with $n$ balls, there are exactly $n - 1$ outcomes that do not result in a $1$. Using independence, you can multiply these probabilities together to find the probability of the event that you obtain no balls with $1$'s on them. Finally, take a complement to find that the answer is $1 - \frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{7}{8} \cdot \frac{8}{9} = \frac{17}{45}$.

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-)